# Unknown issue in PostgreSQL Function

Tags: postgresql, active-directory, windows-10, odbc

I develop an application using VB6 and ODBC that fetch data from PostgreSQL function.

I used the function "F0006" to get information about item code, name, etc.

So far, my application runs smoothly on the current PC ( Windows 7 SP1 ). Because of the end of the support of Windows 7, we buy a new PC to replace the current that has Windows 10 installed.

We set up the same ODBC connection based on the currently running one and Connection success. But when we try to test our application to fetch the data, it seems can't find the function "F0006" and throw an unknown function message in the New PC ( Windows 10 ).

FYI, PostgreSQL is managed by others, and we don't have Admin DB access to it, and Active Directory is used in our network.

But if we try the same application in the current PC ( Windows 7 ) and other PC that using Windows 10 that has not configured to network AD, the application can get fetch data from the function.

Where could be the source of the problem?

Thanks